# Assign Variables without Rewriting URL

Tags: .htaccess

I have a series of links in my admin panel that look like this:

```
/admin-panel/index.php?foo=visual&bar=icons
/admin-panel/index.php?foo=visual&bar=templates
/admin-panel/index.php?foo=visual&bar=templates&baz=1
/admin-panel/index.php?foo=logs&bar=activity
/admin-panel/index.php?foo=logs&bar=transactions
/admin-panel/index.php?foo=logs&bar=transactions&baz=23
```

I want to use a structure:

```
/admin-panel/visual/icons
/admin-panel/visual/templates
/admin-panel/visual/templates/1
/admin-panel/log/activity
/admin-panel/logs/transactions
/admin-panel/logs/transactions/23
```

How do I structure the .htaccess file to hide the index.php name and assign the GET **(foo, bar, baz)** to their respective variables without rewriting the URL? Thank you!

Comment: "without rewriting the URL?" - ??? Why do you not want to rewrite the URL? ... You need to rewrite the URL. That's what URL-rewriting is for. However, this isn't something you do only in `.htaccess` since you need to actually change the URLs in your application first - the URLs that you link to in your HTML source ("admin panel") need to actually look like your desired URL structure (otherwise you're not actually hiding anything).

Comment: I apologize if I'm using the wrong language, but what I mean is when it goes to that link, I want the URL to still appear with the desired structure but still function as if I'm going to the index.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index.php?foo=([^&]+)&bar=([^&\s]+) [NC]

RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule (^(?!.*?.css$|.*?.js$|.*?.png$|.*?.jpg$|.*?.gif$|.*?.pdf$|.*?.ico$))(.*)$ index.php?foo=$1&bar=$2 [L,QSA]

Usage = These rules will take url like /admin-panel/index.php?foo=visual&bar=icons to /admin-panel/visual/icons and so on.

Comment: Thank you! XAMPP still refuses to cooperate, but this works on my live server, and now I see how the formatting works.

Comment: @Aerdan You likely need to enable `.htaccess` overrides on your local development server (XAMPP). eg. `AllowOverride All` in the server config / appropriate `<VirtualHost>` container.

Comment: @Aerdan Just to clarify, you do still need to actually change the URLs in the application - it's not clear from your question whether you have done this? The "redirect" from `/index.php?foo=<value>&bar=<value>` (first rule) is only really necessary if these URLs are indexed by search engines or linked to by external third parties (in which case it should be a 301, not a 302 as stated above) - which is unlikely to be the case for an "admin panel". This redirect should not be required for your site to function.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan You need to fix the code formatting in your answer. As written, there are several special characters omitted from the unformatted regex that make it incorrect if simply copied

Comment: However, the regex in the last `RewriteRule` is incorrect (even when correctly formatted). The first backreference `$1` is always empty. eg. Given a request for `/admin-panel/visual/icons` (assuming the `.htaccess` file is located in the `/admin-panel` subdirectory) it will rewrite the request to `index.php?foo=&bar=visual/icons`, not `index.php?foo=visual&bar=icons` as expected. (?) @Aerdan